# Attach a static object to an armature (replace a model's head)

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

I'm well versed in Davinci Fusion, but I'm just trying to learn Blender.

I have a model of an astronaut, that is fully rigged with an animation (swaying back and forth). I am looking to replace his head/helmet with another model, in this example, a planet. When static it looks great, I just move the planet over his head and size it up. Perfect for my purposes, I don't need to remove the existing head.

However, the animation sways back and forth, while the planet stays still

I haven't animated it at all, but I need the planet to behave as if it was the astronaut's head.

How do I add the planet to the character rig so that it moves with the character?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the planet, shift select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode, select the head bone and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> *(Parent to) > Bone*. Or join the planet to the body (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>), select the mesh in *Edit* mode, and in the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups*, select the group of the head (called by the name of the bone that is supposed to control it) and click on the *Assign* button.

Comment: Thanks a ton, that did it.