# How would I attach a Hat Object to a Head Object so that the former moves when you reposition the latter, without using the Join function?

Tags: parent, pose-mode

I have a 3D model consisting of a fully rigged figure (That I downloaded from a sharing library) and a hat with no armature or rigging (That I created from scratch).

How would I go about creating the parent\child relationship so that when I reposition the head in pose mode the hat stays in the same relative location (It moves with the head).

I want them to remain separate objects, and not joined together as one piece of geometry.

I'm moving over from DAZ to poser and I have no understanding of how to do this either in terms of Blender's UI or it's internal logic.

Comment: check my answer here, it must be what you're looking for: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237331/attach-a-static-object-to-an-armature-replace-a-models-head/237344#237344

Comment: Parent the hat to the head bone i’d say